# How to get the total staked EGLD for a given address?

Tags: multiversx

The following endpoint

```
https://api.elrond.com/accounts/{address}/stake
```

E.g.:

https://api.elrond.com/accounts/erd1hw78kxyj353x52hmmq6dzxgexynwt4m29q2uvpq6xdm90z3halvsl7cn6g/stake

returns

```
{"totalStaked":"0"}
```

but the staked total is different than 0 for the given address.

Is there any API endpoint that returns the real staked value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `delegation-api.elrond.com`, try:

[https://delegation-api.elrond.com/accounts/{address}/delegations](https://delegation-api.elrond.com/accounts/%7Baddress%7D/delegations)

E.g.:

https://delegation-api.elrond.com/accounts/erd1hw78kxyj353x52hmmq6dzxgexynwt4m29q2uvpq6xdm90z3halvsl7cn6g/delegations

which returns

```
[
   {
      "address":"erd1hw78kxyj353x52hmmq6dzxgexynwt4m29q2uvpq6xdm90z3halvsl7cn6g",
      "contract":"erd1qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqpqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq8hlllls7a6h85",
      "userUnBondable":"0",
      "userActiveStake":"1114814108508273514",
      "claimableRewards":"3162326474680405",
      "userUndelegatedList":[
         
      ]
   }
]
```

The field `"userActiveStake":"1114814108508273514"` shows the stake value (`1.1148 EGLD`).

Comment: Hello,
Is there a swagger or some documentation for delegation-api.elrond.com endpoint?